# How to get the value/string out of a ql-editor with selenium

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I want to get the string out of the ql-editor.

This code below, works for other text fields like email/password text field and other too. But in the ql-editor it wont work. The variable `checkText` receives a Null.

```
    public static void SendKeysElement(IWebDriver webDriver, string statusMessage)
    {

        IWebElement Field = webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@class='ql-editor']//p"));
        Field.SendKeys("Do this and this");

        Thread.Sleep(500);
        string checkText = Field.GetAttribute("value");

        if (maxTries < 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("String not found");
        }
        else if (checkText != "Do this and this")
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            maxTries--;
            SendKeysElement(webDriver, statusMessage);  
        }
        Console.WriteLine(statusMessage);
    }
```

And here is the inspect:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your **p** element (which contains entered text) doesn't have **value** attribute, so you need to do like this:

```
string checkText = Field.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to retrieve the `value` of a P tag. `value` is used with INPUTs, etc. that do not actually contain the text inside the tag. In this case the tag is a P so use

```
string checkText = Field.Text;
```

---

Having said that, you are doing too much in your method. The name is `SendKeysElement()` but you've hard coded not only the locator but the text sent along with validations. You should break each major action out into a separate piece of code. Make `SendKeysElement()` generic enough that it can be used to put text into any element and add a wait.

```
public static void SendKeysElement(IWebDriver webDriver, By locator, string text)
{
    new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(locator)).SendKeys(text);
}
```

Create another method to get text from an element (and add a wait) and make it generic enough that it's reusable.

```
public static string GetText(IWebDriver webDriver, By locator)
{
    return new WebDriverWait(webDriver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(locator)).Text;
}
```

Now in your test, it should look like

```
string text = "Do this and this";
By qlEditorLocator = By.XPath("//div[@class='ql-editor']//p");
SendKeysElement(webDriver, qlEditorLocator, text); ;
Assert.AreEqual(text, GetText(webDriver, qlEditorLocator), "Verify ql Editor string");
```

Comment: IWebElement does not contain `getText();`

Comment: @Beardy You didn't put a tag for the language so I thought it was Java. It's been corrected to C#.

Comment: Hey thanks ill check that out, what you wrote. FYI: I hardcoded the string only for the question. In real, the method receives the string from another class and then there are a few other parameter which are important. The sendkeys method is being used 22 times during my selenium test and is reuseable.